# How can E. coli affect C. elegans expression?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, microbiology, bacteriology

Plasmids can be transferred to *E. coli*. These transformed *E. coli* can be fed to *C. elegans* to silence its gene expression by RNAi.

How can *E.coli* release RNAi to *C. elegans*? Even if we assume *E. coli* could enter cells of *C. elegans* for being intracellular Bacteria, it is hard to imagine that RNAi will exit *E.coli* directly and enter *C.elegan*'s cells? Normally, no cells or bacteria will release RNA or genomic material outside of their cells?

Comment: @Chris Is there a way of merging this question with this one http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/38586/how-c-elegans-is-used-for-siliencing-genes/38597#38597 ? While they are duplicate questions, this one asks the question in a clearer, more precise manner?

Comment: "Normally, no cells or bacteria will release RNA or genomic material outside of their cells?" Horizontal Gene transfer in Bacteria. Human immune system Neutrophils and Neutrophil Extracellular Traps...

Comment: [This post](http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/23534/3340) provides some additional information on how dsRNA is taken up by *C. elegans*

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as bizarre as it may seem, that is what happens. The *E. coli* express a double-stranded RNA hairpin (under the regulation of an inducible promoter), and the RNA contains a sequence derived from a *C. elegans* gene.  When the worms eat the bacteria they grind them up in their pharynx, and release the cell contents (including the induced RNA) into the worms' gut. The gut cells are able to absorb the dsRNA  and transport it to other cells as well. The RNAi pathway processes the inhibitory RNAs to down regulate the target gene.

Comment: Now *that* is surprising! +1. I tried to edit the question. Could you check if it's OK? It's not really my expertise.

Comment: You can also add a note on RNA transporters in *C.elegans* (*Sid1/2*). Though I am not sure, I guess that *C.elegans* (or perhaps related organisms) expresses these transporters more than other organisms that we know.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Ilan amd you had given similar answer to a question of mine about c.elegans. I think my question cud be merged with this one. ( amnt able to provide the link.... using app)

Comment: First of all, gut cells can absorb the dsRNA, but we are talking about the whole body's cells in C.elegans! If we transform RNAi of EGFP, it will silence the whole body's EGFP... or not?

Second, RNAi is made by E.coli or C.elegans? I am not talking about dsRNA. If RNAi is made by C.elegans, it means C.elegans must absorb the dsRNA releasing from E.coli. As far as I know, dsRNA might be bigger than proteins... is it possible to absorb the dsRNA directly? And also, back to the first question, how can dsRNA expend to the whole body of C.elegans to silence most of cells' gene in the whole body?

Comment: @RogerL. You are confusing the term RNAi, which is a biological regulatory mechanism that degrades mRNA, with small dsRNA, which can trigger the RNAi pathway. The bacteria synthesize the dsRNA, and this is released when the bacteria die. The _C. elegans_ cells absorb, or incorporate those bacterially synthesized dsRNAs AND contain transporters that spread the dsRNA between adjacent cells. So yes, EGFP expressed in bodywall muscle will be silenced by dsRNA ingested in the gut. The RNAi complex exists in all worm cells.

Comment: Two worm genes that regulate other worm genes using this pathway are _let-2_ and _lin-4_. They do not encode proteins; they encode small interfering RNAs that bind to mature mRNAs from other genes--protein coding genes. Once the _lin-4_ transcript binds to its complementary target that dsRNA triggers the RNAi degradation pathway.  You can also inject dsRNA into worms (but is is labour-intensive), or you can synthesize dsRNA _in vitro_ and just soak the animals in it for the same effect as feeding them engineered bacteria.